# pallet-society issue to build runtime-benchmarks

Tags: benchmarking

When build runtime-benchmarks, we start to having issue with pallet-society. See the error details below

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `successful_origin`
    --> /Users/home/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/19162e4/frame/society/src/lib.rs:1268:1
     |
1268 | impl<T: Config> EnsureOrigin<T::Origin> for EnsureFounder<T> {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `successful_origin` in implementation
     |
     = help: implement the missing item: `fn successful_origin() -> OuterOrigin { todo!() }`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0046`.
error: could not compile `pallet-society` due to previous error
```

The command used to build runtime-benchmarks

```
cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks
```

We are using polkadot-v0.9.16. I have removed all the pallet-society reference from our project, the problem still persists. From the Cargo.lock file, seems like it's part of the kusama-runtime.

This command is used to work with polkadot-v0.9.13. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In this end, errors like this means some crates are not being correctly imported into the runtime with the appropriate feature flags. You will need to hunt to see where this feature is being enabled, when you don't want it to be.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi, thanks Shawn. That works. Much appreciated. Should have checked existing questions before I ask a new one. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry you ran into the issue!